# Show Text or Images from iOS-App to Chromecast Remote Display

Tags: swift, uiview, chromecast, google-cast

Wondering if it is possible to display Text (or images) from a iOS-App to a Chromecast Remote Display ?

Any help in this appreciated

Comment: Based on the fact that the App Store has apps not made by google that can do that I would say yes. [Example App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-video-cast-best-chromecast-media-viewer/id733144626?mt=8)

Comment: This is obvious, thank you. The swift code I am looking for is a so-called 'remote display' type of Chromecast app (i.e. not a typical streaming video cast app). In particular, I am looking for a way to render text on to a remote-display app in swift. Any idea to that ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way to display dynamically changing text towards Chromecast. As a workaround, you can make a web page instead where you will push the text message, and then the web page instead will be the one that will be displayed by Chromecast. However, you will have to implement a refresh every time a new text is set (which, so far by doing a quick search, isn't possible at the moment).

Comment: @AFAIK: thank you very much for this idea. Hmm - in my case I would like to show a game-score and this might be doable by several webpages (for each score one - but, hmm, might be rather tedious and inflexible at the end)... Thanks again, still, for your input here !